# Count and Group By an Entity (Not an Entity's Property)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following entity model. I omitted a lot of properties on each entity for brevity's sake.

```
public sealed class Platform {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Platform's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if an Object is Equal to This Platform.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">
    /// An object to compare.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A boolean true if the object is equal to this platform. A boolean false otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        bool isObjectPlatform = obj is Platform;
        bool isObjectIdEqual = isObjectPlatform && (obj as Platform).Id == this.Id;

        return isObjectIdEqual;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Platform's Hash Code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The platform's hash code, equalling the platform's unique identifier.
    /// </returns>
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Id;
    }
}

public sealed class Capture {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Platform.
    /// </summary>
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if an Object is Equal to This Capture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">
    /// An object to compare.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A boolean true if the object is equal to this capture. A boolean false otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        bool isObjectCapture = obj is Capture;
        bool isObjectIdEqual = isObjectCapture && (obj as Capture).Id == this.Id;

        return isObjectIdEqual;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Capture's Hash Code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The capture's hash code, equalling the capture's unique identifier.
    /// </returns>
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Id;
    }
}
```

What I basically want is a LINQ query, backed up by an EF of course, that will get me the count of **Captures** grouped by an entire **Platform** entity. I want to be able to return a reference to each **Platform**, instead of one of its properties, and the count of each **Capture** associated with it.

I did this query and it works great:

```
var query = this._defaultContext.Captures
                .Include(m => m.Platform)
                .GroupBy(m => m.Platform.Id)
                .Select(m => new {
                    PlatformId = m.Key,
                    Count = m.Count()
                });
```

But as you can see, I am grouping by the **Platform's** *Id* property. What I would rather have is this:

```
var query = this._defaultContext.Captures
                .Include(m => m.Platform)
                .GroupBy(m => m.Platform)
                .Select(m => new {
                    Platform = m.Key,
                    Count = m.Count()
                });
```

This does not work. It just gets a count of 1 for each record in the database. It looks it does not know to group by an entire entity. I was hoping it could by differentiating between each **Platform** by way of the **GetHashCode** and **Equals** method implementations but no luck.

Anyone ever run into a scenario like this? Any way around it? Or do I have to manually do it. I would hate that since it would probably result in some kind of N + 1 query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @2kay I want to be able to return a reference to the entire entity for further use outside of the context of my data access layer, instead of having to issue an extra query to get the entity by its key which was used for the grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = this._defaultContext.Captures
                    .GroupBy(m => m.Platform.Id)
                    .Select(m => new {
                        Platform = m.FirstOrDefault().Platform,
                        Count = m.Count()
                    });
```

Comment: Did not work. "m.Key" is still equal to the Platform Id property.

Comment: I get a really bad System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Platform,Capture]] GroupBy[Capture,Platform](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Capture], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Capture,Platform]], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[Platform])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @agarhy, I was afraid of that) now it looks like bad code, but shold work.

Comment: Sweet it worked. I had to make a slight change in order to avoid an exception and to pull the actual Platform entity in the "Select": m.FirstOrDefault().Platform. I agree there must be a better way but I can't seem to figure it out. I would think that it would compare by equality but that's life I guess. I'll mark this as the correct answer until I discover a better way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @agarhy, in fact, replacing `First` with `FirstOrDefault` you replace `InvalidOperationException` with `NullReferenceException` :) Btw, `InvalidOperationException` is unlikely to be thrown because groupings returned by `GroupBy` always contain at least one object.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I always get a `System.NotSupportedException` no matter what. When I replace it with `FirstOrDefault`, it works with no problems :)

Comment: I think you should say "oh that [Unacceptable word here] EF" :). But thanks again for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are taking this approach. Consider implementing two-way navigation between Platform and Capture (See [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620)) then you can include Captures and Counting becomes simple.

```
public sealed class Platform
{
    public ICollection<Capture> Captures { get; set; }
    // the rest of the stuff
}
```

...

```
var query = this._defaultContext.Platforms.Include("Captures").Select(p => new { Platform = p, CaptureCount = p.Captures.Count() });
```

On translation to SQL this should get expressed as something like:

```
SELECT Platform.Id, Platform.Name, COUNT(Captures.*)
FROM Platform LEFT OUTER JOIN Capture ON Capture.Platform_Id = Platform.Id
GROUP BY Platform.Id, Platform.Name
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about this and it would definitely work (+1). But I have lazy loading disabled and I don't want to pull an entire collection of Captures every time I pull a Platform.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` by default if you don't specify one.  In turn, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` looks to see if `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` and uses it if so.

So the answer is to implement `IEquatable<T>` as well:

```
public sealed class Platform : IEquatable<Platform> {

    public override bool Equals(Platform obj) {
        return this.Equals((object)obj);
    }
    // rest of your code here 
}
```

HOWEVER

I doubt that this will be translatable into SQL.  You may instead have to define a navigation property from `Platform` to a list of `Captures`, which would give you the objects in one query.

To specify an IEqualityComparer just implement that interface in a class:

```
public class PlatformComparer : IEqualityComparer<Platform>
{
    public bool Equals(Platform p1, Platform p2)
    {
        if(p1 == null !! p2 == null) return false;
        return p1.Id == p2.Id;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Platform p)
    {   
        if(p==null) throw new ArgumentNullExceltion("p");
        return p.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use it in your `GroupBy`:

```
.GroupBy(m => m.Platform, new PlatformComparer())
```

Comment: Did not work. Stepping through the debugger, the method implementation is not being invoked at all either. How do I specify a comparer? Maybe that might work?

Comment: Did you leave the `Equals` override you had in there before?  You'll need both.

Comment: Yep both Equals methods are there.

Comment: Also try returning `this.Id.GetHashCode()` in GetHashCode.  I didn't think it would  make a difference but it might for some strange reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. See the answer I marked for a solution. If you figure out a better approach and feel like sharing, please do. Thanks again.